# R raster::shapefile() seems to overwrite ID when writing SpatialLinesDataFrame

Tags: shapefile, r, sp

I am creating a "nested" SpatialLinesDataFrame like so:

```
lines.list <- list()

id.vect <- c("A", "B", "C")

for (lines.index in 1:3) {
  
  line.list <- list()
  
  for (line.index in 1:2) {
    
    # create random path data:
    path <- matrix(data = rnorm(20), ncol = 2)
    
    # transform them to a line:
    line <- Line(path)
    
    # add to line list:
    line.list[[line.index]] <- line
    
  }
  
  # convert the line list to a Lines object:
  lines <- Lines(slinelist = line.list, ID = id.vect[lines.index])
  
  # write to lines list:
  lines.list[[lines.index]] <- lines
  
}

# Convert the Lines list to a SpatialLines object:
spatial.lines <- SpatialLines(LinesList = lines.list)

# create a data frame with the Lines IDs:
id.df <- as.data.frame(x = id.vect, row.names = id.vect)
colnames(id.df) <- "Lines_ID"

# convert to SpatialLinesDataFrame:
spatial.lines.df <- SpatialLinesDataFrame(sl = spatial.lines,
                                          data = id.df,
                                          match.ID = T)
```

Which works perfectly fine. The SpatialLinesDataFrame looks like this:

[image]

However, when I write this SpatialLinesDataFrame to a shapefile and read it back in, like so:

```
# go to output directory:
setwd("/output/directory")

# write output shapefile:
shapefile(x = spatial.lines.df, file = "output_shapefile.shp", overwrite = T)

# read the shapefile back in for comparison:
output.shapefile <- shapefile("output_shapefile.shp")
```

then the resulting SpatialLinesDataFrame (`output.shapefile`) looks different:

[image]

In particular, the Lines IDs have changed from 'A', 'B', 'C' to '0', '1', '2'. So I lost my originally defined IDs, likely while writing the shapefile. How can I prevent this?

Alternatively, is there a better way to create such a "nested" SpatialLinesDataFrame? My approach seems unhandy when even more levels need to be nested.

I am using R version 3.6.2 through RStudio version 1.2.5033 on macOS 10.14.6.

Comment: You should probably steer clear of the attribute name "ID" when working with shapefiles. Many implementations copy the Esri use pattern of generating a phantom integer field with a zero-based offset with that name. I suggest you use "LINE_ID" for the name of your character field.

Comment: Ok, how do I change this? I never used "ID" explicitly, it is just the name of the Lines() function argument.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51894753/9808337) suggests that slot names can't be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prevent that happening easily. The values in those IDs aren't written to the shapefile. When the shapefile is read back, R will create new unique IDs for each unique item.

If you want to save and restore an R object identically, use `saveRDS`:

```
> saveRDS(spatial.lines.df, file = "out.RDS")
> testin = readRDS("out.RDS")
> identical(spatial.lines.df, testin)
[1] TRUE
```

which works for most R objects.

I don't see why this is "Nested", and I don't see the value in keeping an ID in the list of lines the same as a column in the data frame - once constructed the matching between lines and data frame rows is in the order of the items in the two slots.

Comment: As to the "nesting", imagine you have lines for households, which you want to group by municipality, then in turn group those by region, state, nation etc. So there should be a different level of grouping for every level of spatial aggregation, which should be reflected by the list structure of the SLDF. I was wondering if that is possible for an arbitrary number of levels.

Comment: As to the IDs, is it therefore sufficient to keep them in a column in the data frame?